# Threading issue in heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I am having a threading issue in an iOS app. This is a large app that has been evolving for a few years. (I am on of many contributors to this project and have only a deep understanding of some parts of it).

In some cases, the app undergoes a background refresh which fires tableview delegate methods. Occasionally this causes the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'
```

I have done some digging into this problem and determined that during the background refresh there are cases where tableview delegate methods are not called from the main thread.

So, I can check to see if I am on the main thread while inside of heightForRowAtIndexPath.

If am not on the main thread, I can call performSelectorOnMainThread in an attempt to get the cell height, the only problem being that that heightForRowAtIndexPath returns before the selector returns, so my cell height will be zero. So, this is a 'chicken before the egg' situation. How would one force a call to the main thread in heightForRowAtIndexPath and be sure it does not return before performSelectorOnMainThread has completed? Or is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to fix the wrong thing. Don't fix `heightForAtIndexPath`, fix the code that tries to reload or update the table from a background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the heightForRowAtIndexPath, it just seems you are reloading tableview in a background thread. 
Try doing this

```
[self.tableview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: `reloadData` is a method of `UITableView`. `self` is probably a view controller, not a table view.

Answer (score 4):

You can Achieve background Threading using GCD for this you don't have to manually manage the data.GCD will perform all for you.

> Here is a piece of code

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //// DO some Background Processing Like Data Fetching
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // Do some UIUpdates in your case call TableView Datasource
        [yourtable reloaddata];
    });
});
```

Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        //// Do background tasks Like Data Fetching
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          // do UI related tasks

        }
    }
```